# mvc razor combine model property into string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Consider the following partial view Common.cshtml ...

```
<input id="CommonControl" />
```

I want to render it with ...

```
@Html.Partial("Common", "PersonNamespace")
@Html.Partial("Common", "CarNamespace")
```

and the final output to be...

```
<input id="PersonNamespaceCommonControl" />
<input id="CarNamespaceCommonControl" />
```

How would I define the above partial with a model to accomplish this?

For example...

```
<input id="@modelCommonControl" />
```

wouldn't work.  What would be the correct Razor syntax?

Comment: That's not a common usage for `PartialViews`! You should define your own Html Helper!

Comment: I created a very simple example to show what I am trying to accomplish.  My partial view would be much more involved than this simple example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `@Html.PartialView()` accepts only 2 types, say, `model` and `ViewDataDictionary` as second arg, Not a `string`! So you need to implement partial views as desired. You can Define a ViewModel for Partial View like this example:
ViewModel:

```
public class Partial{
    public string name {get; set;}
    //other fields
}
```

Partial:

```
@model project.ViewModels.Partial
<input id="@string.Concat(Model.name,"CommonControl")" />
```

With considering to avoid model conflict in one page.

Comment: Ok, that works, and thanks.  Just fyi, you can pass a string as a model since it is an object type.  As a matter of fact, you can pass any scalar as well as it will be boxed (but would have to be cast in the View).  Not the best implementation, but it can be done.